# warning "@schematics/angular@0.0.49" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34"

Tags: angular

I created new angular application using angular/cli and whenever yarn add any new packages , it warns that "@schematics/angular@0.0.49" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34".

can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8767) with Angular CLI 1.6.0. You can safely ignore it, it will be fixed in 1.6.1.